# NameError: name 'acc' is not defined in pyspark accumulator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, accumulator

Test Accumulator in pyspark but it went wrong:

```
def test():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
    rdds = sc.parallelize([Row(user="spark", item="book"), Row(user="spark", item="goods"),
                            Row(user="hadoop", item="book"), Row(user="python", item="duck")])

    acc = sc.accumulator(0)
    print("accumulator: {}".format(acc))

    def imap(row):
        global acc
        acc += 1
        return row

    rdds.map(imap).foreach(print)
    print(acc.value)
```

The error is:

```
...
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "test_als1.py", line 205, in imap
acc += 1
NameError: name 'acc' is not defined
```

But I set the `acc` as global variable, how can I write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `imap` is referencing a global variable that doesn't exist (the assignment in `test` only creates a local variable in that function). This simple program (without Spark) fails with the same error for the same reason:

```
def foo():
    blah = 1
    def bar():
        global blah
        print(blah)
    bar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Assigning `acc` at the module level works:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
    rdds = sc.parallelize([Row(user="spark", item="book"), Row(user="spark", item="goods"),
                           Row(user="hadoop", item="book"), Row(user="python", item="duck")])

    acc = sc.accumulator(0)
    print("accumulator: {}".format(acc))

    def imap(row):
        global acc
        acc += 1
        return row

    rdds.map(imap).foreach(print)
    print(acc.value)
```

Adding a `global acc` statement to `test` is an alternative if you need to keep the function `test`.

Comment: I cannot set SparkContext in the module level

Comment: Ok, adding a reference to acc at the global level is alternative if you need to keep the function test e.g. acc = None. Answer updated.

Comment: And I should add two `global`, one in `test`, and another in `imap`

Comment: Actually, the module level initialisation is not required. Just adding the global statement to test is sufficient. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
global acc
```

global is used to access the globally declared variable but your variable is declared inside a function and you can directly access it inside your nested imap function.

For more example of global visit [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/).

Comment: If removed it, it raised another error:`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'acc' referenced before assignment`